# Length of Interval

Tags: measure-theory, limits

I'm currently going through Terence Tao's book on measure theory and I'm having a little trouble with one of his exercises.  He tells us to observe that:

$|I| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{N}\#\left(I \cap\frac{\mathbf{Z}}{N}\right)$

where $|I|$ is the length of any real interval, $\#|A|$ is the cardinality of a finite set, $N$ is an integer, and $\frac{\mathbf{Z}}{N}=\{\frac{n}{N}: n \in \mathbf{Z}\}$

I can convince myself that it's true for easy intervals like $(2,3)$.  But I'm having trouble proving it for the general case, or for "hard" intervals like $(2.113,2.114)$.  Does anyone have any tips to get started?

Comment: what is n in definition of $\mid I \mid$ ? is it $N$?

Comment: Sorry, $N$ and $n$ are just integers.  This isn't a definition, but a claim that $|I|$ the length of the interval, is equal to that limit.

Comment: Actually, the formula require the limit being taken on N

Answer (score 11):

Assume WLOG that $I=[a,b]$ with $a\leq b$.

Let $N$ be a positive integer and $x\in I\cap\frac{\mathbb Z}{N}$, $x=\frac{q}{N}$

Then $Na\leq q\leq Nb$, hence $\#(I\cap\frac{\mathbb Z}{N})= \lfloor Nb\rfloor-\lceil Na\rceil+1$ and $$\frac{1}{N}\#(I\cap\frac{\mathbb Z}{N})=\frac{\lfloor Nb\rfloor-\lceil Na\rceil+1}{N}=\frac{Nb-Na}{N}+O(\frac{1}{N})=b-a+o(1)=|I|+o(1)$$